# change contents of images in html without creating more pages

Tags: css, html, web

I would like to kindly ask the following.I have created a simple website from a free html css template that i have found and i am facing the following issue.

I want to create some kind of gallery but i have to many pictures divided in many categories and i dont know if there is a way of not having to create too many pages.

I want to have 1html which will have some sort of data container and depending on the category swlected the related images and text should be loaded without having to create 1html for every category.

I am relatively new to webblsites and i am not familiar with what can be used for that purpose and if it is possible to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that would be PHP - You can have a single page, and have the content generated dynamically.

It wouldn't be very wise to go through an entire category-based gallery just in one answer, but if you google you should be able to find loads of simple php based galleries around.

Alot of them require SQL databases to generate the 'gallery' view, with thumbnails etc.

Comment: another solution would be jQuery to show/hide parts of the page (some sort of tabbed view). there are plenty of solutions, but none are easily tackled by someone just learning basic webpage markup.

Answer (score 0):

Its simple, keeps the photos in same category under single div. Use Jquery to show hide based on your selection.

HTML

```
<input type="radio"  value="category1" name="type" />Category1
<input type="radio"  value="category2" name="type"/> Category2
<div class="category1" style="display:none;">
<ul>
<li><img src="photo1.jpg"/>Photo1</li>
<li><img src="photo2.jpg"/>Photo2</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="category2" style="display:none;">
<ul>
<li><img src="photo3.jpg"/>Photo3</li>
<li><img src="photo4.jpg"/>Photo4</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('input[type="radio"]').click(function(){
        if($(this).attr("value")=="category1"){
            $(".category2").hide();
            $(".category1").show();
        }
        if($(this).attr("value")=="category2"){
            $(".category1").hide();
            $(".category2").show();
        }

    });
});
```

You have different options, instead of radio button, you can use anchor links.. Do Some research.

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/tkncvjfp/

Answer (score 0):

This is more of an idea rather than complete code for you to plug into your site.

Here's something I thought of for organizing pictures: keep the image URLs in a multi-dimensional array according to categories and subcategories. Then dynamically fill your gallery based on the selection in a dropdown menu. And this is all shown in one page.

The dropdown menu would show the categories as options.

HTML:

```
<select id="menu">
    <option value="0">Choose pictures</option>
    <option value="1">Animals</option>
    <option value="1.1"> - Cats</option>
    <option value="1.2"> - Dogs</option>
    <option value="2">Cars</option>
    <option value="3">Hats</option>
</select>

<div id="gallery"></div>
```

The array in Javascript would look something like:

`[[[cat1,cat2],[dog1,dog2]],[car1,car2],[hat1,hat2]]`

So choosing `Cats` shows pictures of cats, while choosing `Animals` would show pictures of both cats and dogs.

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3ru9dh55/1/).